# SQL Server same server multiple connection request

Tags: sql-server, request, database-connection

Is it possible to include `user id` and `password` in a a same request on SQL Server?

I want to compare results from two databases in the same server but with different permissions.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT textField
FROM databaseONE.dbo.someTable 
) AS OLDVALUE

WHERE (textField) NOT IN 

(SELECT equivalentTextField
FROM databaseTWO.[dbo].otherTable
)
```

how to add `[user id = user1 | password = password1]` for `databaseONE` and `user id = [user2 | password = password2]` for `databaseTWO`

Thank you.

Comment: You can use separate connection strings to get the values from databases and compare your values in your code instead of comparing them in database.
OR
You can create another user who have permissions for both the databases.

Comment: You can try creating a linked server and use Sql Queries.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look to this and feedback. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two reasonable options here:

1) Create a user that has permission across both databases and use that user to perform this query.

2) If 1 is unsuitable, have the calling program make two calls, one to each database with the respective set of credentials and then compare the results in the calling application.

Comment: I'm already using a read only shared user.
I wanted to see if an other solution is possible Purely SQL / T-SQL.